# React Native axios GET method to get all data from subpages and display them

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, react-hooks, axios

Hello i'm new with axios and i wanna to display all my data from subpages to screen but I have some trouble because when I display them it shows me the data from the last subpage instead of all of them at the bottom I throw the code how I download the data through axios. How do I display them all ?

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
async function test() {

for (let id = 1; id < 3; id ++) {
        axios.get(`https://api.jsonbin.io/b/61f98c361960493ad1865911/${id}`)
            .then(({data}) => {
                setData(data.commentData)
                console.log(data.commentData)
            })
            .catch((error) => console.error(error))
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    test()
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting your `data` state in each loop, so the last loop iteration is the one that you see.

```
async function test() {
  for (let id = 1; id < 3; id++) {
    axios.get(`https://api.jsonbin.io/b/61f98c361960493ad1865911/${id}`)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        setData(data.commentData) // <-- overwrites previous state
        console.log(data.commentData)
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }
}
```

Use a functional state update to correctly update from the previous state.

```
async function test() {
  setData([]);
  for (let id = 1; id < 3; id++) {
    axios.get(`https://api.jsonbin.io/b/61f98c361960493ad1865911/${id}`)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        setData(data => [...data, data.commentData]) // <-- append new data
        console.log(data.commentData)
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }
}
```

You could also map an array of Promises and use `Promise.all` to get a single array of resolved data values.

```
async function test() {
  const requests = [1,2,3].map(id => axios.get(`https://api.jsonbin.io/b/61f98c361960493ad1865911/${id}`));
  try {
    const dataArr = await Promise.all(requests);
    setData(dataArr.map(({ data }) => data.commentData));
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but now I have a problem displaying this data on the screen.

Comment: @BobMaster And what is the issue there? `commentData` appears to be an array of objects with a `commentContent` property. Try something like `data.map((commentData) => commentData.map(({ commentContent }) => /* return element rendering commentContent */ ))`.

Comment: Previously, I redirected this data to FlatList and called it in the card component. <FlatList numColumns={2} data={data} keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id} renderItem={({item}) => { return <Card item={item}/>; }}/> and const Card = ({item}) => { return ( <Text style={{fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 17, marginTop: 5}}> {item.commentContent} </Text>); the point is that the data from commentContent are displayed below each other

Comment: @BobMaster With the code from my answer `data` is effectively an array of arrays. If you want all the comments to be a single flattened array then try `data={data.flat())} in the `FlatList` component, or flatten it when setting state `setData(dataArr.map(({ data }) => data.commentData).flat());`. Otherwise you'll need to do something like `renderItem={({ item }) => <Card item={item[0]}/>}`. Does this make sense?